# Is there a way to look at previous versions of code in an R Statistics file?

Tags: r, file, rstudio

Is there a way to look back at previous code in a file? For instance maybe be able to revert to an earlier saved version or somehow see changes the file code went through?

Comment: Start using [tag:git]?

Comment: It is a personal .R file MrFlick. So no way to pull up previous changes then?

Comment: R files are just text files. Regular text files have no "Track Versions" as some file formats can introduce (e.g., docx). As @Jaap suggested, use `git` (or subversion or mercury or CVS or RCS or anything that google returns as a "tool for file version control".

Comment: Okay thanks for the answers yall!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Unless your changes are tracked in some sort of source control (like [git](https://git-scm.com/)) or you keep backups of your files, there is no way to see previous version of a script file. A .R script is just plain text files. They do not store their own history just like other documents or images on your computer don't either. Sorry.

If that's something you want to do in the future, Rstduio makes it easy to integrate with git. Check out this guide to [Connect RStudio to Git and GitHub](https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html)